# Text shifting when printed

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with jasper report. I have created report using iReport. I do pass data using the servlet to the report template. When viewing the report there is a lot of spaces in the report when i view it in html. When i do print the report using an applet,the problem is that the text shifts upwards. I will realy appreciate for your assistance. Or is there anyone who has ever had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution. The problem was with my css. Exporting jasper to html uses the deafult css styling use in your application. Changin td and tr styling made the report look better. 
Thanks.